# How could I roll content all the time in page?

Tags: javascript, css

I`ll receive logs from servers per 5 seconds.I need to add new messages to the page,such as

> append/repend

But the question is how could I let it just like a living show to notify users new logs are coming...it`s much similar to [Log.io](http://logio.org/),I have watched its code.But it can't fit my situation for I add new nodes and css style to each log.
And my code is:

```js
$("#log-content").append('<p>' + str + '</p>');
$("html, body").animate({
  scrollTop: $(document).height()
});
```

Sometimes the result looks very strange.So I need some help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the server to notify the users of new 'events' then you'll need to use sockets (This is how Log.io does it) to push new items to the client. Either that or have a method on the server that the client can poll via a looping ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. Logs will be send to client every 5 seconds from the server.So what I need to do is how to show it like logs is cominmg & changing. And I found a solution finally.

```js
var obj;       // arrary of logs
var index;
function renderLog() {
    if (index < obj.length ) {
         //change the css style of the log, and set display is unvisible.
        $("#log-content")  .prepend(obj[index++]);
        slideDown(3, function() {    renderLog();    });
    }
}
```

I've tried "for“ loop and ”animate“,but it's not works that well.It sames like all the logs execute "animate" function at the same time.The code just add events.
Hope the question can help others like me.